# how do i set a short URL or a username for my page in Google plus

Tags: google-plus

I have created a page for my company on Google Plus and i would like to make a Shot URL instead of the Auto Generated number.

I am looking to do it under Google+ without using third parties like
http://gplus.to/

Some people and companies have it like:
https://plus.google.com/+hughjackman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, pretty URLs are not currently (yet) available to anyone, and it might take some time to be invited to use one by Google.

If it is available for you, it should be able to select a URL on your own G+ page, in the box at the bottom right.

Here are Google's FAQs about this: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340?hl=en&topic=2400106#